# ошибки линковщика

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017

Пишу простое консольное приложение 
При попытке скомпилировать проект линковщик выдает следующее:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Соответствующие переменные валяются в `IIndexer.h`

```
#pragma once
#include <Windows.h>

 DEFINE_GUID(CLSID_Indexer,
    0xa888f560, 0x58e4, 0x11d0, 0xa6, 0x8a, 0x0, 0x0, 0x83, 0x7e, 0x31, 0x0);

DEFINE_GUID(IID_IIndexer,
    0xa888f561, 0x58e4, 0x11d0, 0xa6, 0x8a, 0x0, 0x0, 0x83, 0x7e, 0x31, 0x0);


class IIndexer : public IUnknown
{
public:

};
```

От интерфейса наследуется класс Indexer(файл Indexer.h)

```
#pragma once
#include "IIndexer.h"

class Indexer : public IIndexer
{
public:
    virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE QueryInterface(REFIID riid, void **ppv);
    virtual ULONG   STDMETHODCALLTYPE AddRef();
    virtual ULONG   STDMETHODCALLTYPE Release();
private:
    DWORD m_lRef;
public:
    Indexer();
    ~Indexer();
};
```

Нужные мне переменные `CLSID_Indexer` и `IID_IIndexer` используются в `Indexer.cpp`

```
#include "Indexer.h"

Indexer::Indexer()
{
    m_lRef = 0;
}

Indexer::~Indexer()
{

}

ULONG Indexer::AddRef()
{
    InterlockedIncrement(&m_lRef);
    return m_lRef;
}

ULONG Indexer::Release()
{
    InterlockedDecrement(&m_lRef);
    if (m_lRef == 0)
    {
        delete this;
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        return m_lRef;
    }
}

HRESULT Indexer::QueryInterface(REFIID riid, void **ppv)
{
    *ppv = 0;

    if (riid == IID_IUnknown || riid == IID_IIndexer)
    {
        *ppv = this;
    }

    if (*ppv)
    {
        AddRef();
        return S_OK;
    }
    else
    {
        return E_NOINTERFACE;
    }
}
```

В `main.cpp` лежит следующий код

```
#include <iostream>
#include "IIndexer.h"

int main()
{
    IIndexer *indexer;
    CoInitialize(NULL);
    HRESULT res = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_Indexer,
        NULL,
        CLSCTX_INPROC,
        IID_IIndexer,
        (LPVOID*)&indexer);

    if (indexer == NULL) std::cout << "FAILED TO CREATE OBJECT" << std::endl;
    else std::cout << "SUCCESS" << std::endl;

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Попробовал решение по коду ошибки, но не особо получилось. Подскажите,пожалуйста, почему проект не собирается?

Comment: Обработка ошибки сделана неправильно - надо проверять `res`, а `indexer` может быть не нулевым в случае ошибки.

Comment: справедливо, спасибо, приму во внимание

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка возникает из-за того, что вы не определили GUID'ы. Дело в том, что макрос `DEFINE_GUID` необязательно определяет GUID. Если не подключен заголовок `initguid.h`, то этот макрос объявляет GUID как внешний символ. То есть этот макрос должен вызываться как минимум два раза, причем идентичным образом - один или более раз в файлах .h для объявления, и ровно один раз в одном из .cpp файлов для собственно определения.

Решение тут такое: добавьте в один из ваших .cpp файлов следующий код:

```
#include <initguid.h>

DEFINE_GUID(CLSID_Indexer,
    0xa888f560, 0x58e4, 0x11d0, 0xa6, 0x8a, 0x0, 0x0, 0x83, 0x7e, 0x31, 0x0);

DEFINE_GUID(IID_IIndexer,
    0xa888f561, 0x58e4, 0x11d0, 0xa6, 0x8a, 0x0, 0x0, 0x83, 0x7e, 0x31, 0x0);
```

и все заработает.

Comment: спасибо))))))))

Comment: @Anton Leshkevich, если ответ решил проблему, кликните на галочке, пожалуйста.